# Showing that the set of vectors $e_k-e_l$ spans $ V=\left\{ (a_1,...,a_n) \ | \ a_1+\dots + a_n=0 \right\}. $

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

As the title says, I want to show that the set of vectors $$\{ e_k-e_l \ | \ k, l \in \{1, \dots, n \} \}$$ spans the vector space given by
$$
V=\left\{ (a_1,...,a_n) \ | \ a_1+\dots + a_n=0 \right\}.
$$
That means that I should show that any $v=\sum_i a_ie_i\in V$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors $e_k-e_l$. Consider:
$$
\sum_i a_i e_i=\sum_i a_i e_i-\left(\sum_{i} a_i\right) e_j=\sum_i a_i\left(e_i-e_j\right).
$$
Is this sufficient (and correct)?

Comment: Are you trying to show that $\{ e_k - e_l : k \in \{ 1, \dots n \}, l \in \{ 1, \dots, n \} \}$ is a spanning set for $V$? Or are you trying to show that $\{ e_k - e_l : k \in \{ 1, \dots n \}\}$ is a spanning set for $V$, where $l$ is a **fixed** element of $ \{ 1, \dots, n \} $?

Comment: @KennyWong, the former. But I believe my proof still holds, because $\sum_ia_i(e_i-e_j)=\sum_{i,j}a'_{ij}(e_i-e_j)$ (where some $a'_{ij}=0$).

Comment: Yes, I agree with you!

Comment: One small point: I wouldn't describe $\{ e_k-e_l \ | \ k, l \in \{1, \dots, n \} \}$ as a set of **basis vectors**. This is not a basis for $V$: these vectors span $V$, but they are not linearly independent.

Comment: @KennyWong, I didn't make that edit: I simply described $e_k-e_l$ as 'the set of vectors' in the original post.

Comment: Your proof is correct, though you could argue less directly (and arguably simpler). Your space $V$ is the kernel of a linear functional on $\mathbb{R}^n$ so by rank nullity it has dimension $n-1$. Moreover, $\{ e_1 - e_k| 2 \leq k \leq n \}$ is a linearly set of $n-1$ vectors in $V$, so this subset alone is enough to span $V$.